In TA-Lib , Cython.Compiler.Errors.InternalError: Internal compiler error: '_common.pxi' not found
While running a program on pycharm I am getting below error while running on pycharm using python. Unable to run the program due to below error:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib-Precompiled
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (TA-Lib-Precompiled)
> Package :TA-Lib-Precompiled                                                                  
> Python Version : Python 3.12.1
> Cython version 3.0.11

Please help in finding the solution !!

Below are the logs :
> Collecting TA-Lib-Precompiled
  Using cached TA-Lib-Precompiled-0.4.25.tar.gz (276 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python312\lib\site-packages (from TA-Lib-Precompiled) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: TA-Lib-Precompiled
  Building wheel for TA-Lib-Precompiled (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for TA-Lib-Precompiled (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for TA-Lib-Precompiled
Failed to build TA-Lib-Precompiled


                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "Cython\\Utils.py", line 129, in Cython.Utils.cached_method.wrapper
    File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 574, in cimports_externs_incdirs
      for include in self.included_files(filename):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "Cython\\Utils.py", line 129, in Cython.Utils.cached_method.wrapper
    File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 556, in included_files
      include_path = self.context.find_include_file(include, source_file_path=filename)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 299, in find_include_file
      error(pos, "'%s' not found" % filename)
    File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Errors.py", line 178, in error
      raise InternalError(message)
  Cython.Compiler.Errors.InternalError: Internal compiler error: '_common.pxi' not found
  [end of output]
  
>  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib-Precompiled
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (TA-Lib-Precompiled)


Are you running a program or trying to install a package?

There are wheels available but for only  Linux distributions for Python 3.9 - 3.11.

running program using these lib

Try using Python 3.11 and see whether it works. If it still doesn't work, then you have to get WSL (which provides a Linux environment on Windows)

How to get WSL (which provides a Linux environment on Windows) ?

You can look at my answer

The stable release of TA-Lib-Precompiled only has wheels for Python 3.8 - 3.11 for Linux.
You can install The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which provides a Linux environment on your Windows machine and then use a supported Python version such as Python 3.11.
See How to install Linux on Windows with WSL for detailed instructions on this.
